# Append element to input control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Two input buttons that allow user to upload files

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="files" multiple><br/>                                           
<div id="selectedFiles"></div>
```

into the selectedFiles div i append a list of file names:

```
$('input:file').on('change', function() {
    //$('.file').bind('change', function() { // is duprecated
    var files = this.files;
    var listOfFiles = [];

    for(var i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
        //var filename = files[i].name + "<br />";
        //$("#selectedFiles").append(filename);
        listOfFiles.push(files[i].name);
    }

    $('#selectedFiles').append(listOfFiles.join("<br />"));
});
```

What i need to do is to append the list of files under each button. any idea on how to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `$( '#selectedFiles' ).append` with `$(this).after`. Probably should wrap all the files inside a list for cleanliness. Here's a better way:

```
$(this).after('<ul><li>' + listOfFiles.join('<li>') + '</ul>')
```

Here's the final code (I cleaned it up a little):

```
$(function() {
  $( '.upload_files_input' ).on('change', function() {
    var file_names = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.files).map(function(file) {
      return file.name;
    });
    $(this).after('<ul><li>' + file_names.join('<li>') + '</ul>');
  });
});
```

Comment: Put your code in a jsFiddle so I can help you better.

Comment: @Kob_24 Here you go: fixed code + cleaned it up :) https://jsfiddle.net/fk2zzhkq/1/

Comment: But i dont understand why its not working when i added to my website :(

Comment: Do you have jQuery on your website?

Comment: yeah i do, the think is that its listing all the element under one button

Comment: Is your website live? Link it here and I'll try and help

Comment: one sec i will upload it

Comment: It's working for me: http://s32.postimg.org/m9ilep551/Ashampoo_Snap_2016_04_27_21h29m32s_001_Chrome_Le.png

Comment: Wait... nvm, i see the problem

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem: you're `<input>`s have the same ID. Give each one a unique ID (and also update the `<label>`s) and you should be OK.

Comment: wtf i didnt see it sorry man. silly mistake.. thank you for ur time :)

Comment: how about if i want to reload the appended element if i make new selection from same button ?

Comment: Sure, just before the `$(this).after` line put `$(this).next('ul').remove()`. The `'ul'` will check if there is a list, so it won't accidentally destroy your other stuff

Comment: @Kob_24 No worries :)

Comment: Not really, I mostly just read documentation, and trial-and-errored... and lots of Googling. LOTS of Googling... MDN is by far the best documentation, stick to that one. Most of the courses online or textbook teach you far too slowly and narrowly IMHO.

Comment: cool sounds good :), actually iam a backender and not frontend but i had to fix this assignment. Anyway have a nice day and thank you again for ur help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110362/discussion-between-lerouche-and-kob-24).

Comment: Thanks! Helped me too